# Pandas check multiple columns for condition and subtract 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created the following Dataframe (which in reality is 1000+ rows and 20+ columns):

```
d = {'col1': [0, 0, 4, 6], 'col2': [3, 4, 0, 0], 'col3': [0, 10, 0, 0], 'END': [0, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

Out:
   col1  col2  col3  END
0     0     3     0    0
1     0     4    10    0
2     4     0     0    0
3     6     0     0    0
```

Now I want to create a loop for every column by index to do the following: check if the current item in the column is greater than 0 and if yes, if the item in the column next to the right is equal to 0. If both are true, then subtract 1 from the item in the column and move to the next column and repeat.

So far my best try was with a while loop to find the correct fields:

```
Counter = len(list(df))
i = 0
while 0 < Counter:
    if df.iloc[:,i] > 0 and df.iloc[:,i+1] == 0:
        df.iloc[:,i] - 1
    i = i +1
```

This code however raises a value error.

My desired result would look like this:

```
   col1  col2  col3  END
0     0     2     0    0
1     0     4     9    0
2     3     0     0    0
3     5     0     0    0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be pretty fast:

```
df[df.ne(0) & df.shift(-1, axis=1).eq(0)] -= 1
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3  END
0     0     2     0    0
1     0     4     9    0
2     3     0     0    0
3     5     0     0    0
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option

```
df.sub(df.shift(-1, axis=1).eq(0)).clip(0)

   col1  col2  col3  END
0     0     2     0    0
1     0     4     9    0
2     3     0     0    0
3     5     0     0    0
```